# Android Studio problems since the last update to 0.8 version

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm following the Google I/O conference and just a week before they announced that Android Studio 0.8 is available for downloading. Before that I used 0.6 and I was developing an application. Now I'm having both 0.6 and 0.8 on my Ubuntu. I added all the update from SDK for Android Watch and TV and all the Material Design stuffs. And today when I opened my project in the 0.8 version, after a few updates of some things, I'm receiving an error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0-rc1
```

If someone has any idea what is this all about - share please. I tried to pull my project from my repository in GitHub, but without any result. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you have declared a dependency on version 21 of appcompat-v7 in your build.gradle.

At this time, the preview of the Android L support libraries only works with apps that declare the L preview as their min SDK.

Either revert to a previous version of the support library (I believe the latest is `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0`) or update your project to support a minimum of `'L'`.

Comment: So how can I change back to 19?

Comment: I updated the answer with the dependency line for the last version. From the [Support Library revisions page](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions).

Comment: I don't want to develop for the last version - I want to back to 19 to finish my project.

Comment: By the last version, I meant the last stable release prior to the L preview. `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.+'` will give you that version and should fix this issue.

Comment: Okey, so where can I find that 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.+' ?

Comment: You probably have a similar line in your build.gradle that either doesn't specify a version or specifies version 21.

Comment: Okey, I fixed that and now the drawable resources are missing and so on... Thank you so much.

Comment: This fixed my issue by changing the `appcompat-v7:+` to use a specific version in the build.gradle dependencies. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue like that before. After I updated to 0.8.1, it showed an error below when compiling my previous projects.

"uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0-rc1".

This is how I fixed it.

1. In your project, find **build.gradle** file in **app** folder and open it.
2. At **dependencies** section, change the value of `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7'`. For example, in my case, it was `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'`, and I changed it to `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'`. Of course, you could change it to `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'` if you like.

I hope it would help. Let me know if you are still stuck on it.

Answer (score 1):

just try this:

```
android {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 20 //or whatever you want
        buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14 //or whatever you want
            targetSdkVersion 20 //or whatever you want
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    }

}
```

and if you have another module in your project, check manifest files in those modules too.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems. Although I'm not sure *exactly* what caused the problem or which step fixed the issue, I did the following and ultimately got things working again:

1. I closed down Android Studio
2. I ran SDK Manager and and checked that everything was up to date. I have the following installed:

   - Android SDK tools Rev. 23
   - Android SDK Platform-tools Rev. 20
   - Android SDK Build-tools Rev. 20
   - Android L (API 20, L preview)
   - Android 4.4W (API 20)
   - Android 4.4.2 (API 19)
3. I restarted Android Studio and started a new (blank) project to test and ran it -> Success!

I found the process pretty finickity, so your mileage might vary. Let me know how you go.

Comment: Yes, if I open a new blank project it will work perfectly, the problem is that my project were developed on the previous 0.6 Android Studio version and when I migrate on 0.8, with all these updates and stuffs, now first I was receiving the top error for Manifest merged fail. Now I can't find my drawable resources. I had three styles for buttons defined as drawable and after the update, I can't find my drawable folder. I don't know what's coming next if I fix that. After each error there is one more. And I'm little pissed off from all of this situation. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I found the solution.

```
dependencies {
    compile ('com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.0'){
        force = true
    }
    compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'){
        force = true
    }
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'){
        force = true
    }
}
```

I think that instead of 20.0.0, you can specify a different version if you use less than 20 targetSdkVersion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I made the following changes to the dependencies section in build.grade file located in the app folder.
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0' to 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'

[image]